# Android custom keyboard ,sending media

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, ime

I have developed an custom keyboard and also added some images to the view,
my goal is to send the clicked image directly to the current app(for eg: message app or watsapp).So, How can i implement this one?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that right now in the form you wish. The connection between the currently opened application and keyboard accepts only text (emoticons are text, too). What you can do is to send `Intent` to the currently opened application and hope, that app will handle that:

```
public void passImage(String uri) {
    Log.d(ImageKeyboard.class.getSimpleName(), "Image passed: " + uri);
    Intent intent = createIntent(getApplicationContext(), getCurrentInputBinding(), uri);
    try {
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Intent createIntent (Context context, InputBinding inputBinding, String uri) {
    String[] packageNames = context.getPackageManager().getPackagesForUid(inputBinding.getUid());
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
    sharingIntent.setPackage(packageNames[0]);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(uri));
    return sharingIntent;
}
```

SMS app, Facebook and Gmail will work that way, however any other app may not. This is the best you can do right now.

**Important info:**
From [Android 7.1 Developer Preview](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/10/android-71-developer-preview.html) it is possible. Info from the site:

> Android 7.1 also adds these much-requested developer features to the
>   platform:
>
> **Image keyboard support** — expands the types of content that users can enter from their keyboards, letting them express themselves
>   through custom stickers, animated gifs, and more. Apps can tell the
>   keyboard what types of content they accept, and keyboards can deliver
>   all of the images and other content that they offer to the user. For
>   broad compatibility, this API will also be available in the support
>   library.

Comment: IntentFactory?.. what's this

Comment: Just a helper class. I removed it's references for the clarity of this example